# AngularJS inline edit doesn't POST to correct URL ... i.e. doesn't send the item ID ... ? ...

Tags: angularjs, post, inline, editing

I have a controller in AngularJS with only this code:

```
app.controller('PublishersController', function($scope, scaffold) {
    scaffold($scope, {model: "Publishers"});
});
```

And view with such code:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="publisher in items">
    <tr ng-show="!ui.isEditing($index)">
      <td>{{ publisher.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="email in publisher.emails">{{ email }}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a ng-click="ui.edit($index)">&#9998;</a> |
        <a ng-click="ui.remove($index)">&#x2718;</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="ui.isEditing($index)" ng-class="{error: publisher.$errors}">
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="publisher.name" placeholder="Name" />
        <ul ng-show="publisher.$errors" class="error">
          <li ng-repeat="name in publisher.$errors.name">{{ name }}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea type="text" ng-model="publisher.emails" placeholder="Emails" ng-list /></textarea><br/>
        <i>(use `,` as separator)</i>
        <ul ng-show="publisher.$errors" class="error">
          <li ng-repeat="email in publisher.$errors.emails">{{ email }}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a ng-click="ui.edit()" title="Save">&#x2611;</a> |
        <a ng-click="ui.edit(false)" title="Cancel">&#x2612;</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

All is working fine - I have listing and inline editing.

So - I modified the code and made another page - for prices. So, I get the listing and the inline editing functionality.

The problem is that when I press the "Edit" button and after that I submit - the POST goes to the "/prices" URL instead of "/prices/{price_id}". As is does in the case with the publishers.

So ... what am I doing wrong? ... (I can't find any place this URL is defined or set or whatever ...)

Answer (score 0):

After a log of dumping and testing I found out the problem.

=== 1 ===

So, for models in Angular this project uses a library `angular-model.js`, in which a module is defined:

```
angular.module('ur.model', ...
```

and after that - we have a scaffold module that uses the model. It's in `angular-scaffold.js`, where we have:

```
var module = angular.module('ur.scaffold', ['ng', 'ur.model']);

module.factory('scaffold', ['model', ...
```

And my front-end controller uses this scaffold module.

=== 2 ===

There is a server side code, that returns the JSON for the item, and this JSON is used in the `model` module. And this JSON have to have a property for the URL for this item, including the item ID. And this URL gets used to view the item or to edit the item - depending on weather you send GET or POST request to it.

And as you can guess - the server side didn't return this `item-URL` property in the JSON for the item. When I did it - the problem got solved.